I want to view selected data in cascading dropdown in .NET Core
I have creation page of cascading dropdown that value store in database. This "Save" operation works ok. But while fetching the data from the database, it is not getting selected accordingly.
I have used an Ajax call on the page that blind all my data in dropdown. And put if condition that if Viewbag.Update = 1 then use $('#ddl1 selected').val("1") but it's not working in live. It's the same functionality which works in developer mode

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Viewbag.Update = 1  is assignment statement,you should use   Viewbag.Update == 1 . you can learn more from those  website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/sbkb459w(v=vs.100)  and  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/53k8ybth(v=vs.100)
